# VBA - Macro to extend selection to end of current table column, then find and replace only within that selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been asked to update a very old VBA macro that creates a selection from the current cursor to the end of the current table's column. It then searches that selection and replaces certain characters with new characters. In Word 2003, it works flawlessly, replacing characters only inside of the selection. In Word 2010, though, it replaces characters outside of the selection. Any help would be much appreciated. I've searched far and wide, and tried many variations of this code.

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdColumn, Extend:=wdExtend
With Selection.Find
  WordBasic.EditReplace Find:=" ", Replace:="", Direction:=0, MatchCase:=True, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=0
  WordBasic.EditReplace Find:="-", Replace:="–", Direction:=0, MatchCase:=0, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=0
  WordBasic.EditReplace Find:="0", Replace:="–", Direction:=0, MatchCase:=True, WholeWord:=True, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=0
  WordBasic.EditReplace Find:="^p", Replace:="", Direction:=0, MatchCase:=True, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=0
  WordBasic.EditReplace Find:="^l", Replace:="", Direction:=0, MatchCase:=True, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=0
End With
```

Comment: What if, instead of using Selection, you find the column of your selection and then set your range?  Once the range is set I would think it would only search inside that range.

Comment: Thanks, @hessr17. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a range based on the selection.

Creates a selection from the current table cell to the end of the column:

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdColumn, Extend:=wdExtend
```

Creates a range object equal to the current selection:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Range.Start, Selection.Range.End)
```

Performs a Find and Replace based on myRange, in this case, using wdFindStop so it does not wrap to the beginning or ask the user if they want to search from the beginning:

```
With myRange.Find
  .Text = " "
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

With myRange.Find
  .Text = "0"
  .Replacement.Text = "-"
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

myRange.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```